# Should we always check for Optional when using streams in Java8?

Tags: null, java-stream, option-type

The method get() always become marked in my intellij idea. Compiler says that i should use method isPresent as well. My colleagues say that i should not pay attention to that notice. Anyway, i decided to ask here.

```
    List<Integer> list  = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(3);
    int result = list.stream().reduce((accumulator,element) ->
    accumulator*element).get(); // this get() is mentioned above
```

Comment: to make clear, ide sends warning to me, when using get() without isPresent().

Comment: Naming the lambda parameters “`accumulator`” and “`element`” is misleading, as that’s not what these parameters are. Since the function must be associative, both arguments can be an element or a partial result. Besides that, when you use `reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b)`, you don’t have the problem with the `Optional`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your reduce is Optional.
Optional.get method can throw error : [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--)
if value is not present. In your case it is present and seems like the warning can be ignored.

There could be case where you have your List as input parameter for the method. In those cases you would need to check if it is empty before running your *reduce* method or check if Optional has value via *isPresent* method to avoid this exception [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

Answer (score 0):

**First try to create an Optional and then get() it after checking isPresent.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list  = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(3);
        int result = 0;
        Optional<Integer> optional = list.stream().reduce((accumulator, element) -> accumulator*element);
        if(optional.isPresent()) {
            result = optional.get();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!